# Image thumbnails flashes and then disappears in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, images

I have Windows Vista installed on my machine and I am facing this really annoying problem. Whenever I open a folder having images, image thumbnails appear for an instant and they are replaced by standard file icon. Argh...

Points to note:

- Setting "Always show icon, never thumbnail" is **unchecked**
- Running Windows Aero theme (with transparency support)
- Have 4GB of RAM on my machine so memory is not a problem

Please can you suggest a solution?

Comment: I had no thumbnail previews of images in Windows 7 and didn't know about the first bullet point, which fixed the issue for me. Sorry it's not working for you.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and have not yet found a solution.  Have not yet tried turning off shell extensions as suggested by Choy.  I will say that some image thumbnails *do* occasionally display (maybe 2 out of 50), but it appears entirely random.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [site](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-music-pictures-video/230339-thumbnails-generate-then-disappear-explorer.html) it is due to the **archive-flag is set** (the post is about network drives but maybe it's unrelated).

After unchecking this flag thumbnails work properly (**tested**)!

EDIT:
Does only work if images get the flag unchecked one by one. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Vista, but in Windows 7, as well as the "Always show icons, never thumbnails" check-box in 'Folder settings', there's also a "Show thumbnails instead of icons" check-box in 'Performance options' ('System properties > Advanced > Performance Settings' in Win 7).
Is this setting available in Vista also?

Comment: Yes and it is un-checked. Still no luck. :(

Comment: Mine is checked.  Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Autoruns (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and turning off all your Shell Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the disk, ensuring that thumbnails are included:
Right-click menu of hard disk, Properties, General tab, Disk Cleanup.

Some people report that uninstalling MS Publisher fixed the problem (if you have it installed).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hard disk is not full. I had 390MB left and Vista would not create the thumbs.db file until I freed up more disk space, then it worked.